# How to display data from a service in an Angular Datatable

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-datatables

I have an Angular Datatable that I am trying to use with a service. I have a test version of the service (a Mock) that has an
array of of information that I would like to display.

Furthermore, I would like to be able to select the data in a particular row by clicking on it. Once a row is clicked on,
I need to be able to process the selected data.

My service code is fairly straightforward:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export class PersonInfo {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public firstname: string,
    public middle: string,
    public lastname: string,
}

const thePeople = [
  {
    id: 1,
    firstname: 'John',
    middle: 'H',
    lastname: 'Doe',
  }
];

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MockPersonService {

  constructor() { }

  getAllPeople(): UserInfo[] {
    return thePeople;
  }
}
```

The component that will display the table is below:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MockPersonService, PersonInfo } from '../people/mockperson.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-persontable',
  templateUrl: './persontable.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./persontable.component.css'],
})
export class PersontableComponent implements OnInit {
theOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
peopleList: PersonInfo[] = [];

  constructor(perService: MockPersonService) {
    this.peopleList = perService.getAllPeople();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.theOptions = {
      columns: [
        {title: 'ID', data: 'id'},
        {title: 'First Name', data: 'firstName'},
        {title: 'Middle Initial', data: 'midInitial'},
        {title: 'Last Name', data: 'lastName'},
      ],
      rowCallback: (row: Node, data: any[] | object, index: number) => {
        const self = this;
        // Unbind first in order to avoid any duplicate handler
        // (see https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/87)
        $('td', row).unbind('click');
        $('td', row).bind('click', () => {
          self.rowWasSelected(data);
        });
        return row;
      }
    };
  }

  rowWasSelected(smData: any): void {
    alert('Selected: ' + smData.firstName);
  }
```

The contents of my HTML file for the component is provided below:

```
<table datatable [dtOptions]="theOptions" class="row-border hover">
```

The MockPersonService is declared as a provider in my ngModule:

```
    ...
  providers: [MockPersonService]
    ...
```

All of the code for the component is based on instructions given on the Angular Datatables site
(https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/advanced/row-click-event).

The problem is that while I can display the table with the appropriate headers, there appears to be no example of how to
populate the table with the contents of peopleList! All examples appear to assume that the user is going to use some
ajax method in the component to get the data to be displayed in JSON format -- something which I eventually intend to do
but *not* in the component. The service (which is declared as a singleton provider in the ngModule file) will be sending
the request to the server for the people objects, which it will receive in JSON format, place into its peopleList object, 
and share the peopleList object with the PersontableComponent and several future components.

How does one populate an Angular Datatable with the information provided in an array provided by a service? In this 
example, I need to be able to take the contents of the peopleList array and display them in my table.

Comment: You were right mentioning ajax, in the examples on the tab "with ajax" you can see how to do it, (using a service instead of the http.get).
basically you have to add dtTrigger

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are not giving the datasource to dataOptions. This will fix the issue:

```
ngOnInit() {
    var self = this;
    this.theOptions = {
      data: this.peopleList,
      columns: [
        {title: 'ID', data: 'id'},
        {title: 'First Name', data: 'firstName'},
        {title: 'Middle Initial', data: 'midInitial'},
        {title: 'Last Name', data: 'lastName'},
      ],
      rowCallback: (row: Node, data: any[] | object, index: number) => {
        const self = this;
        // Unbind first in order to avoid any duplicate handler
        // (see https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/87)
        $('td', row).unbind('click');
        $('td', row).bind('click', () => {
          self.rowWasSelected(data);
        });
        return row;
      }
    };
  }
```